# PHP Incomplete Class OOP

Tags: php, mysql, oop

hello i have this code

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()) {

        $this->_error = false;

        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            $x = 1;
            if(count($params)) {
                foreach($params as $param) {
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                    $x++;
                }
            }

            if($this->_query->execute()) {
                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
            } else {
                $this->_error = true;
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

and when i run it, it's says that i have error in line

```
$this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
```

The error message says 
**Catchable fatal error: Object of class __PHP_Incomplete_Class could not be converted to string in** 
any help please
thank you

**EDIT**

var_dump of $params

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#1 (6) { 
        ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=> string(4) 
        "User" ["_db":"User":private]=> object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#2 (2) {
            ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=> string(2) "DB" 
            ["connection"]=> NULL 
        } 
        ["_sessionName":"User":private]=> string(4) "user" 
        ["_cookieName":"User":private]=> string(4) "hash" 
        ["_data":"User":private]=> object(stdClass)#3 (7) { 
            ["id"]=> string(3) "144" 
            ["username"]=> string(5) "admin" 
            ["password"]=> string(64) "0611affa6664e471b939cd3197b49e0c3b47d146fc12a472c4275dbd85a7cd67" 
            ["salt"]=> string(32) "458a0dbfbd9bdca381e50b8d753329ea" 
            ["name"]=> string(12) "Artur Papyan" 
            ["joined"]=> string(19) "2013-11-29 07:41:54" 
            ["group"]=> string(1) "1" 
        } 
        ["_isLoggedIn":"User":private]=> bool(true) 
    }
}
```

Comment: What does $params contain? Are there any objects in that array without a __toString() method?

Comment: Are u using serialized objects by chance?

Comment: The params contain the sql syndax, no i dont serialize the objects

Comment: Can you show a var_dump() of $params

Comment: Here is the var_dump();
Because the character limit dont't allow me to write i'll post it like answer sorry

Answer (score 0):

The error says it clear: `$params` contains at least an `__PHP_Incomplete_Class` object that obviously can not be converted to a string to fill your query with.

The reason why you are obtaining `__PHP_Incomplete_Class` objects is due to an unserialization of a session-stored object which class hasn't been loaded previously. So you have to include your session-stored classes before the session start. If you want my advice, autoloading is the best way to load clases thus you can forget of `include`/`require` statements at all. You can find out more info here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: i try and with include, and with include_once i have the autoload function, but on my local server everything work's perfect, on web server i have the problem, on my web server the php version is 5.3>

Comment: @Arturik1988 Did it work in your local server prior to including the classes before `session_start()`?